# MERGE clause in Neo4j Cypher query not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running neo4j-community-3.0.0-M05.

I am trying out Neo4J Cypher Query Language's MERGE clause. Its explanation is [given](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/get-started/#cypher-getting-started) as follows

> It acts like a combination of `MATCH` or `CREATE`, which checks for the existence of data first before creating it. With `MERGE` you define a pattern to be found or created. Usually, as with `MATCH` you only want to include the key property to look for in your core pattern. `MERGE` allows you to provide additional properties you want to set `ON CREATE`.

I already have following node:

```
(:Movie{title:"Forrest Gump", released:1994})
```

and now I wanted to add a dummy property `addedOn` with dummy value `20160108` to it just to try out `MERGE` clause:

```
MERGE (a:Movie{title:"Forrest Gump"}) 
ON CREATE SET a.addedOn= "20160108" 
RETURN a;
```

However this seems not working:

[image]

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is precisely the expected behaviour.

Since `MERGE` finds your pre-existing Forrest Gump, this node is used. The `ON CREATE` handler will not fire since you didn't create anything.

If you've had a `ON MATCH` handler this one would have been fired since `MERGE`'s match was successful.

Comment: great...just added `ON MATCH`: `MERGE (a:Movie{title:"Forrest Gump"}) ON MATCH SET a.addedOn= "20160108" ON CREATE SET a.addedOn= "20160108" RETURN a;`. Wasnt aware of this.